# dhcpd service restart takes almost 7 minutes in CentOS7

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

I have 110 dhcp scopes in my config file. Everytime I restart the service, it will take it almost 7 minutes to complete. More info below:

```
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]# grep VLAN /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf | wc -l
110
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]# cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]# rpm -qi dhcp
Name        : dhcp
Epoch       : 12
Version     : 4.2.5
Release     : 77.el7.centos
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Tue 01 Oct 2019 04:14:37 AM +08
Group       : System Environment/Daemons
Size        : 1449595
License     : ISC
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Fri 23 Aug 2019 05:22:17 AM +08, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : dhcp-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri 09 Aug 2019 07:10:22 AM +08
Build Host  : x86-01.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://isc.org/products/DHCP/
Summary     : Dynamic host configuration protocol software
Description :
DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) is a protocol which allows
individual devices on an IP network to get their own network
configuration information (IP address, subnetmask, broadcast address,
etc.) from a DHCP server. The overall purpose of DHCP is to make it
easier to administer a large network.

To use DHCP on your network, install a DHCP service (or relay agent),
and on clients run a DHCP client daemon.  The dhcp package provides
the ISC DHCP service and relay agent.
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=3974540k,nr_inodes=993635,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,size=5242880k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,blkio)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot on / type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20052)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvhome on /home type xfs (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvtmp on /tmp type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvvar on /var type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvvartmp on /var/tmp type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvvarlog on /var/log type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvaudit on /var/log/audit type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,seclabel,attr2,discard,nobarrier,inode64,logbufs=8,noquota)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=797300k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
[root@dhcp ~]#
[root@dhcp ~]#


logs when "systemctl restart dhcpd" is executed:
[root@dhcp ~]# 
[root@dhcp ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp polkitd[5349]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5937:354512872 (system bus name :1.30076 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Stopping DHCPv4 Server Daemon...
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Stopping DHCPv4 Server Daemon...
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp named[243904]: resolver priming query complete
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp named[243904]: resolver priming query complete
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Stopped DHCPv4 Server Daemon.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Stopped DHCPv4 Server Daemon.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Starting DHCPv4 Server Daemon...
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp systemd: Starting DHCPv4 Server Daemon...
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.5
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.5
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2013 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2013 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Warning: subnet 192.168.88.0/24 overlaps subnet 0.0.0.0/-26
Nov 10 21:16:56 dhcp dhcpd: Warning: subnet 192.168.88.0/24 overlaps subnet 0.0.0.0/-26
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.5
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.2.5
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2013 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2013 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 10 21:17:12 dhcp dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 class decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 class decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:12 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 60199 leases to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Wrote 60199 leases to leases file.
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Listening on LPF/eth0/50:6b:8d:03:a8:b9/0.0.0.0/0
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Sending on   LPF/eth0/50:6b:8d:03:a8:b9/0.0.0.0/0
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp systemd: Started DHCPv4 Server Daemon.
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Listening on LPF/eth0/50:6b:8d:03:a8:b9/0.0.0.0/0
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Sending on   LPF/eth0/50:6b:8d:03:a8:b9/0.0.0.0/0
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp dhcpd: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
Nov 10 21:23:13 dhcp systemd: Started DHCPv4 Server Daemon.
```

Is almost 7 minutes to restart with that number of dhcp scope normal? Any way to make it restart faster? Thank you

Comment: Can we also see your `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` Configuration File, @bad rabbit? Also, apparently you have four warnings, such as "_Warning: subnet 192.168.88.0/24 overlaps subnet 0.0.0.0/-26_". Can you check them out?

Comment: Hi, feel free to download/view the dhcpd.conf from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11t3fGS4y3EAQDdCqoxiGo0qADXe_o481)